# Insert exact data value into the database

Tags: php, mysql

Please I need help with this. I have this code and it's working as I want it but when inserting into the database, it's inserting the id and the state_id I used as the primary and foreign key to create relation between the two tables in the database. I want it to be inserting the exact value not the id or state_id. Thanks.

```
<?php
 include 'dbconnect.php';
 $query = "SELECT `id`,`states` FROM `states`";
 $result1 = mysqli_query($dbconnect,$query);
 $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result1);
 if ($rows){
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){
   $states[] = array("id" => $row['id'], "val" => $row['states']);
 }
}

 $query = "SELECT `id`, `state_id`, `local_government` FROM `local_governments`";
 $result2 = mysqli_query($dbconnect,$query);
 $rows2 = mysqli_num_rows($result1);
 if ($rows2){
   while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
   $local_government[$row2['state_id']][] = array("id" => $row2['id'], "val" => $row2['local_government']);
  }

   $jsonStates = json_encode($states);
   $jsonLocal_government = json_encode($local_government);
}

 if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
     $stateOforigin = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['stateOforigin']));
     $LGA = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['LGA']));

     $sql = "UPDATE `sono` SET `stateOforigin`='$stateOforigin', `LGA`='$LGA' WHERE `eMail`='$email'";
     $check = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $sql);
     header ('location: form2.php');        
    ?>



    <script type="text/javascript">
    <?php
      echo "var states = $jsonStates; \n";
      echo "var local_government = $jsonLocal_government; \n";
  ?>
     function loadStates(){
      var select = document.getElementById("statesSelect");
      select.onchange = updateLocal_government;
      for(var i = 0; i < states.length; i++){
      select.options[i] = new Option(states[i].val,states[i].id);          
     }
   }
     function updateLocal_government(){
      var statesSelect = this;
      var state_id = this.value;
      var local_governmentSelect=document.getElementById("local_governmentSelect");
  local_governmentSelect.options.length = 0; //delete all options if  any present
      for(var i = 0; i < local_government[state_id].length; i++){
      local_governmentSelect.options[i] = new Option(local_government[state_id][i].val,local_government[state_id][i].id);
      }
   }

 </script>
   <body onload='loadStates()'>
   <p style='padding-left: 0px; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold'>State Of Origin</p>
        <p><select name="stateOforigin" class="userarea" id="statesSelect"></p></select>
        <p style='padding-left: 0px; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold'>Local Govt. Area</p>
        <p><select name="LGA" class="userarea" id="local_governmentSelect">
        <option value="Null">Loading</option></p>
        </select>
</body>
```

Comment: easiest way to fix it is to use the required value twice in `new Option()` so you get `<option id='value'>value</option>`

Comment: not quiet understandable question. What results you get now and what would you like to get? Plus you have $email var mentioned but not initialised.

Comment: I have the id and the state_id inserted into the database but what I want is the exact name of the state to be inserted into the database.

Comment: No, you don’t want that – not if you want to do it _right_. Normalization is the keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you are using
`new Option(states[i].val,states[i].id)`
this results in 
`<option value = states[i].id>states[i].val</option>`

When you submit the `form` the `value` of the `option` is used in `$_POST`, not the text between the `<option></option>` tag. That text is just for us humans, so we understand what we are selecting.

Changing the command to
`new Option(states[i].val,states[i].val)`
will result in
`<option value = states[i].val>states[i].val</option>`
Now the wanted value is used in `$_POST`.

What @CBroe is saying, from Normalization perspective, is true too but maybe not what you want.

Comment: Thanks @RST. I have tried your solution, it's input the correct value  but the second selector option is not loaded.

Comment: I don't know what you mean.

Comment: What I mean is the answer you gave is now working. I am now getting the exact value into the database. But the second selector option which is local governments is not loaded. You can check from the code.

Comment: When I passed the val twice, it's inserting the correct value but the second selector option is not loading.

Comment: I understand. You are using `var state_id = this.value;` which is no longer true. You will have to either retrieve the state_id from `states` by searching for `states_val` or you can do something like `new Option(states[i].val,states[i].id+'_'+states[i].val)` which will hopefully result in `<option value = states[i].id_states[i].val>states[i].val</option>`. Now when you need the id or the val you just have to split the value into two parts and use the part you need. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks... I have tried `new Option(states[i].val,states[i].id+'_'+states[i].val)`  but not working. You mentioned splitting. Please could you guide me more on this?

Comment: It seems you didn't understand what I was doing. In your initial code you had the state_id, so you could use it. In my suggested code the state_id was replaced with state_value, you lost the ability to use state_id with this one. My suggestion was to use an id-string that holds both (value and id) separated by a character you could use to split the string back to id and value in case you needed either one. Take a look at split() function.